# Calling SQL Functions much slower when using SqlCommand Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, performance, user-defined-functions

I am calling a SQL Function (UDF) from my C# ASP.Net application. The function I am calling requires one parameter of type "uniqueidentifier".

If I make the call and pass "null" in the CommandText of the SqlCommand, the results come back in about 3 seconds...

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
Command.Connection = (SqlConnection)(DbDataModifier.CreateConnection());
Command.CommandText = "select * from GetLocalFirmLoginsSummary(null) order by Date asc"
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Command.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(); // takes 3 seconds
```

But, if I make the call and pass DBNull.Value as a SqlParameter, the results take over 60 seconds to return...

```
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand();
Command.Connection = (SqlConnection)(DbDataModifier.CreateConnection());
Command.CommandText = "select * from GetLocalFirmLoginsSummary(@CustomerGroupID) order by Date asc"
Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter();
Param.ParameterName = "@CustomerGroupID";
Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier;
Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Param.IsNullable = true;
Param.Value = DBNull.Value;
Command.Parameters.Add(Param);

Command.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(); // takes over 60 seconds
```

If I run the same query in SQL Management Studio, it takes about 3 seconds, even when passing the null as a parameter...

```
declare @CustomerGroupID uniqueidentifier
set @CustomerGroupID = null

select * from GetLocalFirmLoginsSummary(@CustomerGroupID)
```

The Function I'm calling is defined as:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLocalFirmLoginsSummary]
(   
    @CustomerGroupID uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

SELECT     CustomerGroupID, CustomerGroupName, USR, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, createdDate), 0) AS Date, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM         dbo.GetLocalFirmLogins(@CustomerGroupID) AS Logins
GROUP BY USR, CustomerGroupID, CustomerGroupName, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, createdDate), 0)

)
```

...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLocalFirmLogins]
(   
@CustomerGroupID uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

SELECT     vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails.CustomerGroupID, vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails.CustomerGroupName, Organisations.USR, Organisations.town AS FirmTown, 
                  Users.id AS ID, Users.userName, Users.password, Users.isPartner, Users.isFeeEarner, Users.nlisUserName, Users.nlisPassword, Users.email, Users.lastLoginDate, Users.createdDate
FROM         vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Organisations ON vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails.AccountID = CAST(Organisations.id AS nvarchar(50)) RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  Users ON Organisations.clientId = Users.uploadedBy
WHERE     (Users.canLogin = 1) AND (Users.isDeleted = 0) AND (NOT (Organisations.USR IS NULL)) AND 
                      ((vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails.CustomerGroupID = @CustomerGroupID) OR (@CustomerGroupID IS NULL))

)
```

So what causes it to take so much longer when I'm calling the SQL function from C# using a SqlParameter of a SqlCommand?

I'm using SQL Server 2000.

I've searched everywhere and in every way I can think of, but can't find anybody else having an identical problem.

Comment: When you say SQL, you aren't talking about the database-independent [Structured Query Language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), you're discussing the Microsoft database product [SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), correct?

Comment: Quite likely parameter sniffing.

Comment: Did you test if it is specific to null? What with a normal value?

Comment: I would suspect as Martin said this could be parameter sniffing, Try take your parameter variable then assign it to a local variable and use the local variable in the query, it may help the performance.

Comment: In the UDF called GetLocalFirmLogins, which is called by GetLocalFirmLoginsSummary, it filters on "@CustomerGroupID IS NULL".

Comment: @JimRarbs You could try [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) it will show you the SQL calls in the call-tree and you can see what code gets executed for those calls - this will show you if there is some different in the API for your uses.

Answer (score 1):

Jim, could you post the source of dbo.GetLocalFirmLogins please?

As Martin says, this could be parameter sniffing. If it is, a query hint in the code where the seek for @CustomerGroupID may be the best way to "surgically" fix this.

Adding OPTION (LOOP JOIN) to the query in dbo.GetLocalFirmLogins could be fix here.

I think I can also explain why SSMS does not see the problem, while C# does. This part of the query:

```
(CustomerGroupID = @CustomerGroupID) OR (@CustomerGroupID IS NULL)
```

Could have two different plans depending on the ANSI NULL settings of the connection you are coming from. ANSI NULL and the effect is decribed here:

[SET ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

You can see the ANSI settings of your connection by retrieving the results of this query:

[DBCC USEROPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180065.aspx)

SSMS might have a different NULL setting that you C# code and cause a different evaluation of the query.

Comment: I've now added GetLocalFirmLogins to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: BTW, I'm hoping there's a solution that can be implemented in the C# code, as I'm hoping I can then leave it to other people with less SQL experience to adjust the UDF's to suit their needs.

Comment: I've also discovered that it's actually SQL Server 2000 I'm using, not 2008 :(

Comment: I've done a little reading up on parameter sniffing, and unless I'm getting the wrong end of the stick, shouldn't that issue also apply to queries conducted in SQL Management Studio too? If I call my UDF from a Query window in SMS, it's nice and quick. It's only when calling them from my C# code that it's slow.

Comment: @JimRarbs - No. In order for the cached plan your application is using to be reused [many things need to be the same](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18769/schema-qualification-necessary-for-query-plan-reuse/18770#18770). SSMS has different default `set_options` so unless you are using different options from the default it won't reuse the same plan as your application is using. See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe caused by Parameter Sniffing problem in SQL Server.

You can find more detail in following link:

[Parameter Sniffing](https://dotnetforlife.blogspot.ca/2009/11/parameter-sniffing_29.html?m=1)

I hope you'll find this helpful.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for mentioning 'Parameter Sniffing'. I would like to ask..  based no the blogpost, we need to declare variable inside the function. Does that mean... we have to use Multi-statement table-valued functions (MSTVF), no longer with 'Inline table-valued functions'?

Comment: @zeroflaw I've recently seen this post for parameter sniffing and it could help you as well: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/12/21/sql-server-parameter-sniffing-and-optimize-for-unknown/

Comment: Appreciate that~

Answer (score 0):

Differences in performance between Management Studio and .NET code are often related to settings such as ANSI_NULLS.

This may be a bug in SQL Server 2000 - see [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/05eb0bb9-089b-4955-9489-796dfabd7076) which appears to imply that SET ANSI_NULLS ON before CREATE FUNCTION is not taken into account.

I don't have a SQL Server 2000 to test this, but maybe you could try scripting your function.

Comment: It is usually **not** the settings themselves. It is just that the different settings mean that the plans aren't shared between sessions so instead of using the cached plan compiled for the unrepresentative parameters you get a fresh new plan compiled that performs fine. Probably if the OP keeps all settings the same and clears the plan cache the problem will go away (temporarily as it could recur next time the plan is recompiled)

Comment: OK, I've setup my C# connection with the same options as are in SSMS, including ANSI_NULLS set to ON. Now when I call the UDF with the parameter populated with a uniqueidentifier, the cache plan shows it being passed as an nvarchar(36), but when I call it with a DBNull.Value as the parameter, it seems to get passed as an nvarchar(4000), which I'm guessing is causing the performance issue? Why does it not always get passed as a "uniqueidentifier" when I'm specifying to do so in the definition of the UDF?

Comment: I can confirm that the nvarchar(4000) is the issue. If I put a CAST(x AS NVARCHAR(36)) around @CustomerGroupID and the CustomerGroupID column references where possible, the speed dramatically increases. So How do I force the Null parameter value to NOT be passed to SQL as a NVARCHAR(4000)?

Comment: @JimRarbs, you could try setting the Size of the parameter (Param.Size = ...) though why this would be necessary for a UniqueIdentifier I don't know.

Comment: @JimRarbs Changing the text of the query will mean that (again) the bad plan can't be used. There is no particular reason why one would perform better than the other, though looking at your code I'm not sure why it is using `nvarchar` for the parameter datatype at all. Seems odd.

Comment: @JimRarbs - would be interesting to know the datatype of the `vw_CustomerGroupAccountDetails.CustomerGroupID` column - if it's VARCHAR that might help explain what's happening...